# Maple messed up my MuPAD Matlab integration

Tags: matlab, maple, mupad

I have installed a trial version of Maple recently, it has expired and I've already uninstalled it. But today, for my surprise, Matlab symbolic tool is not working properly anymore, I was able to find using google that Maple changes the symbolic tools for its own (without warning or so). But it is not undone after uninstall.

The question is, how can I make Matlab "find" MuPAD again?

error e.g.:

```
symengine
//Undefined function or variable 'symengine'.
```

Comment: Does `which symengine` return anything? It should be something like `[toolboxdir('symbolic') '/symbolic/symengine.p']`. How about `mupadengine`?

Comment: When typing in `path`, do you see the entries `<matlabroot>\toolbox\symbolic\symbolic` and
`<matlabroot>\toolbox\symbolic\symbolicdemos` ?

Comment: @Daniel, eyes, both.

Comment: @horchler, "'symengine' not found." "Undefined function or variable 'mupadengine'."

Comment: Have you checked that the Matlab Symbolic toolbox is actually present in your Matlab install. Can you navigate to `<matlabroot>\toolbox\symbolic\symbolic` (in OS X Finder or Windows Explorer)? If it's not there (or possibly renamed something else by Maple) then you may have to reinstall the toolbox (or all of Matlab if you like).

Comment: @horchler, well, I don't know what should be there, but there is some folders, mupad, symbolic, symbolicdemos and a lot of folders and files inside it.

Comment: Can you find the two `symengine` files (.m and .p) either by searching (Spotlight or whatever Windows has) or by looking in `<matlabroot>\toolbox\symbolic\symbolic`? The next thing you might also try is the [`rehash`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rehash.html) function, e.g., `rehash toolbox`, etc.

Comment: @horchler, yes, both, but the .m file has only commented lines. rehash toolbox didn't work. But, I noticed that C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014a\toolbox\symbolic\ subfolders were not in the Path, so I added it including subfolders and it is done! Working again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set Paths, add with subfolders:

```
 <matlabroot>\toolbox\symbolic\
```